# Have error of syntax but don't know where

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Well, i have a table generator, with the data of mysql db.

First, the code:

> PHP

```
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SQL)){
          $tbl->addCell("<p onBlur = 'editTable(" . $result['id_user'] . ", this, 'Name')' contentEditable = 'true'>" . $result['Name'] . "</p>");
          $tbl->addCell("<p onBlur = 'editTable(" . $result['id_user'] . ", this, 'Username')' contentEditable = 'true'>" . $result['Username'] . "</p>");
          $tbl->addCell("<p onBlur = 'editTable(" . $result['id_user'] . ", this, 'Email')' contentEditable = 'true'>" . $result['Email'] . "</p>");
          $tbl->addCell("<p onBlur = 'editTable(" . $result['id_user'] . ", this, 'Grade')' contentEditable = 'true'>" . $result['Grade'] . "</p>" );
          $tbl->addCell("<input type = 'button' class = 'Edit-TBB' value = 'Edit'>
          <input type = 'button' class = 'Delete-TBB' value = 'Delete'>");
          $tbl->addRow();
      }
```

> AJAX

```
function editTable(id, new_text, column) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "../PHP/Configuracion/edit_grade.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: 'id='+id+'&text='+new_text.innerText,
              success: function(data){
                  alert(column);
              }
          });
      }
```

**Here is the problem:**

I have this `'editTable(" . $result['id_user'] . ", this, 'Name')'`

[In Chrome, it show me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIm5s.png)

if i change the code in Chrome like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI8J9.png) ... It works, but i don't know what i need to change at the code editor.

***What i need to change?***

THANKS!

Comment: Try using double quotes for onBlur value, like you would in in html, by escaping them with '\'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use double quotes for your `onBlur` value since you are using single quotes to denote a js string as a parameter. To do this, you need to escape a double quote in your php. So change the `addCell` calls to look like:

```
addCell("<p onBlur=\"editTable(" . $result['id_user'] . ", this, 'Name')\" contentEditable = 'true'>");
```

Comment: Thanks for all bro!